# Mule JDBC Datasource connection

Tags: spring, jdbc, mule, datasource

I have mule 3.5 db configuration as follows

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="pds" name="pds" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" scope="singleton">
        <spring:property name="password" value="pwd"/>
        <spring:property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/>
        <spring:property name="user" value="user"/>
        <spring:property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
<db:generic-config name="Postgres_Datasource_Configuration"  transactionIsolation="READ_COMMITTED" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration" dataSource-ref="pds"/>
```

my flow looks like

```
<flow name="JDBC-PostgresConfigurationWithDatasource" doc:name="JDBC-OracleConfigurationWithDatasource">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" path="postgresInboundWithDS"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <db:select config-ref="Postgres_Datasource_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM employee]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:select>
    <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[payload]"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

I am always getting the error saying

> The attributes of Element db:generic-config{dataSource-ref=pds, name=Generic Database Configuration, name=Postgres_Datasource_Configuration, transactionIsolation=READ_COMMITTED} do not match the exclusive groups [driver, url, connectionTimeout, transactionIsolation, useXaTransactions] [dataSource-ref]

What I didn't get is I mentioned dataSource-ref, but still it is showing error as mutually exclusive.

I observed the same behavior with oracle connector also.

> But I am able to connect to db when I am not using spring bean datasource.

One more weird thing is, when I was working with mule 3.4 it worked fine. Now, in 3.5 it is showing errors.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message, if you specify `dataSource-ref`, then you can't specify `transactionIsolation`.

So remove the `transactionIsolation` from `db:generic-config`.

Comment: I thought the transactionIsolation might be ignored if I specify datasource until I do not specify url,user,pwd . Thanks

Comment: I just landed in new problem zone. C3P0 is saying could not load driver class.But I has the driver class in classpath. Also for other generic configurations (which are also postgres) I am able to hit the database with same driver class. But for only when I am using datasource it is showing this error.

Comment: One more weird thing is I just tried the same with oracle and is getting the same exception for oracle driver (oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)

Comment: That is weird. Can you test the following: place the C3P0 JAR in the `/lib/user` directory of the Mule Standalone server where you deploy your app.

Comment: I am experiencing weird things. If I create the project with mule esb runtime 3.4 then I am getting c3p0 jar in 'referenced libraries'section when they are mentioned in pom.But when I am creating project with 3.5 runtime I am not getting c3p0 jars even when thy are mentioned in pom.Only postgresql jar is seen in referenced libraries section. I am using Community edition with anypoint studio july release.

Comment: When I am deploying to standalone community server I am getting error due to mule-config not found.But I am deploying to 3.5 CE for which it is not needed I guess.

Comment: It seems part of your issues are Studio related, you may want to ping MuleSoft with it. Eventually you will have to deploy you application to Mule standalone so this is really what matters: can you or can you not deploy your application on standalone with c3p0 and the DB driver packaged in the app itself?